# std::cin.fail() not working like expected in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in an integer from standard input, and I have this code which almost does that, and prompts again if the user enters letters.  However, it has the problem that if the user enters a floating point number like 6.9, then this is accepted as valid input and the function ends.

```
int nr=0;
std::cout << "Vector length: ";
std::cin >> nr;

while (std::cin.fail() ) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Input is not number , try one more time: ";
    std::cin >> nr;
}
```

I want to detect all wrong inputs.  How can I change my code to consider floating point numbers as invalid?

Comment: what is not like this? Could you be more specific please?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem you are experiencing is?

Comment: Please take a look one more time.I am sorry for my inattention.

Comment: @MDDDC: what did you want to happen when you enter invalid input?  The code seems like it's working perfectly fine.  Other than the question of if you want to input doubles, why are you streaming in integers?

Comment: I want my program to failure when input is double like 9.6 ,my code was not working like this.

Comment: @Mooning Duck: Before voting may be first you will make sure that you are right?

Comment: @MDDDC: If I was not right, then therefore "the question is unclear" and it is "unclear what you are asking". Now I see what you meant, but that doesn't mean the question is clear.

Comment: I am very sorry but looking at this "My problem is when user input is double like 9.6 or 6.3 ..." what is unclear for you ?

Comment: @MDDDC: There, I rewrote the text of the question to be very clear.  Look it over and let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much , your reading is more clear. But you should understand , I am not native English reader, I am from Modlova. Thanks for your attention and for this Edit.

Comment: @MDDDC if your intent is that writing anything after the number should count as an error; then just read a single character after you get the number. If the read did not get `\n` then there must have been stuff after the number.

Comment: `cin.fail()` is exactly equivalent to `!cin` btw; you can simplify your loop by making it `while (!(std::cin >> nr))`. And as Mooing Duck says, give some consideration to exiting the loop if `eof()` happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```
      int nr = 0;
      std::cout << "Vector length: ";
      while (!(std::cin >> nr)) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Input is not number , try one more time: ";
      }
```

However, the above code will work with floating points (e.g., "9.8"). It will also create an infinite loop if EOF is entered. If you want strictly integral values do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
  return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(),
    s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}

int main()
{
  std::string num;
  std::cout << "Vector length: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, num);
  while (!is_number(num)) {
    std::cout << "Input is not number , try one more time: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    num.clear();
    std::getline(std::cin, num);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the same like OP's just written differently. It falsely accepts floating-point values too.

Comment: @40two: If EOF is encountered, this is an infinitely loop, OPs is actually better IMO

Comment: @Mooing Duck:  Can you provide with Example ?

Comment: @MDDDC also it still falsely works for double values like I said already: http://ideone.com/Gxl0Ac

Comment: @40two: removing downvote since you now answer the question, but you still have an infinite loop for EOFs.

Comment: If you're going with the numeric limits, why not use the stream size type?